# When comparing a short with a long, which gets casted to which?

Tags: c++, casting

### If i were to write

```
unsigned long long x = ....
unsigned short y = ...
if(x == y) ....
```

Would the long long get casted to short? or would the short get casted to long long? I assume the shorter data type would be casted to the longer data type to prevent truncation/data loss.

Comment: The `unsigned short` will become an `unsigned long long` per the usual arithmetic conversions, but I don't have time to expand on that at the moment.

Comment: of course the shorter type should always be promoted to the longer type. If the longer type was truncated how can the result be correct?

Answer (score 2):

The object of integral type with the less rank is converted to the integral type of the object with greater rank. In your case unsigned short will be implicitly converted to unsigned long long. It is the so-called 'usual arithmetic conversion'.

According to the C++ Standard

> If both operands are of arithmetic or enumeration type, the usual
>   arithmetic conversions are performed on both operands;